# How to make a UITable with columns?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios, uitableview

I was wondering how to make a UITable have columns. Or, is there a better way to create an actual table that looks like a grid. I want to have 3 columns. How can I do this?

Comment: 3 columns on an iPhone? There's not much room for that...

Answer (score 3):

The UITableView doesn't have support for more than one column. However, this can be easily fixed if you create your own custom UITableViewCell-s. You would need to stash three different views into the cell and then add whatever you want in them.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind the fact that you cannot scroll horizontally you can just use a custom `UITableViewCell` to give the *illusion* of columns. If you really want columns (like a spreadsheet) you need to subclass `UIScrollView` and implement `UITableView`-like view caching. Luckily Apple has some sample code which shows how to do this, see [TiledScrollView.m](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/ScrollViewSuite/Listings/3_Tiling_Classes_TiledScrollView_m.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40008904-3_Tiling_Classes_TiledScrollView_m-DontLinkElementID_26)